# How can I efficiently change the color of a BufferedImage?

Tags: java, color

I am trying to change the color of a white [`BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) image.

I do know that you can use `.setRGB(x,y,rgb)` and simply run some nested `for` loops and make changes to one pixel at a time. However, the problem arises when it comes to gradually changing the color instead of instantly doing so. This means I would have to run thousands of loops every runtime, completely ruining the frame rate.

My question is, is there a way to just change the color of an image right away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a bit on what you're specifically trying to do.

If you want to change all of the pixels to a single new color, then most likely the fastest & easiest way is something like this:

```
int width = 512;
int height = 512;
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
Color darkOliveGreen = new Color(85, 107, 47);
g2d.setColor(darkOliveGreen);
g2d.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
```

Note, the above code can also be modified to deal with rectangular subsections of the image.

On the other hand, if you need to quickly evaluate & process the pixels individually for some reason (i.e. change the reds to greens, the greens to blues & the blues to reds), then you'll need to manually access the data buffer that backs the image:

```
byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

From there you can manipulate the pixels quickly without the overhead of issuing a method call for each read & write. The downsides to this approach are:

- Getting used to dealing with a [1D representation of a 2D array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order)
- You'll need carefully read through the field summary portion of the [BufferedImage documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html), have a good understanding of the pixel data format for your image & possibly be comfortable with [bit level manipulations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

Comment: Using `fillRect()`... such a creative solution. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I think one solution is to use `Graphics2D#setXORMode(Color)` but I do not know if it will increase performance, since it requires you to create a new `BufferedImage`. Probably worth a shot, though:

```
public BufferedImage tintImage(BufferedImage image, Color color) {
    BufferedImage tintedImage = new BufferedImage(
                                    image.getWidth(), 
                                    image.getHeight(),
                                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    Graphics graphics = tintedImage.createGraphics();
    graphics.setXORMode(color);
    graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); // NOT 'tintedImage'
    graphics.dispose();
    return tintedImage; // Image will be tinted
}
```

This is all from memory & javadoc so if that code does not work try to change these things:

- Set `color` alpha to 0 (`color = new Color(color.getRed(), color.getGreen(), color.getBlue(), 0)`).
- Change `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` to `BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT`.